# Multiple column, multiple line formatting issues with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble understanding/implementing some formatting with CSS. In this example, the spacing between the Span managed notes and the text below changes depending on how long the last note is. The note span effectively expands into it's own white space on a second line, and starts to run right over the following text with a third line. I'm sure my problem is in the CSS, but I can't seem to grok what the problem is.

```css
section.px_update {
  margin-bottom: 0em;
}

.px_update_container {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.px_upd_note_num {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2em;
  width: 1em;
}

.px_upd_note_note {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 3em;
  width: 70em;
}
```

```html
<section class="px_update">
  <div class="px_update_container">
    <span class="px_upd_note_num">NOTES</span>
    <span class="px_upd_note_num">1</span><span class="px_upd_note_note">Short note:</span>
  </div>
  Following text
</section>
&nbsp;
<section class="px_update">
  <div class="px_update_container">
    <span class="px_upd_note_num">NOTES</span>
    <span class="px_upd_note_num">1</span><span class="px_upd_note_note">Long note: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span>
  </div>
  Following text
</section>
```

Obviously there is also CSS that is inherited from the WordPress theme I am running, and the issue could be in there, but my guess is my problem is in my display setting, or in using Spans. So, hoping for some advice on how to get arbitrary column width and indents, that also allows multiple lines in a second column. I am presenting really dense data, sometimes in 5 or more columns, so I need to do better than the the basic HTML formatting tools. My guess is the solution will teach me something(s) about CSS I need to understand too.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of `position:absolute` css in your code. that's why text is overlapping on each other. i have made some changes in your code.

Here is the updated css:

```css
section.px_update {
  margin-bottom: 0em;
}

.px_update_container {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;
}

.px_upd_note_num {
  width: 5em;
}

.px_upd_note_note {
  width: 70em;
}
```

```html
<section class="px_update">
  <div class="px_update_container">
    <span class="px_upd_note_num">NOTES</span>
    <span class="px_upd_note_num">1</span><span class="px_upd_note_note">Short note:</span>
  </div>
  Following text
</section>
&nbsp;
<section class="px_update">
  <div class="px_update_container">
    <span class="px_upd_note_num">NOTES</span>
    <span class="px_upd_note_num">1</span><span class="px_upd_note_note">Long note: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span>
  </div>
  Following text
</section>
```

Comment: That seems to have had some unintended consequences when there are multiple notes. As in, each note is now a column. That said, is the "right" answer to do this with highly styled Tables rather than Spans? I feel like I tried that some time ago and it didn't work, but I also knew even less CSS then. So maybe I am just continuing down a wrong path?